# PHP mongoDB find by array

Tags: php, mongodb

Alright so I am trying to send bunch of URI's and I hope to get back their ID's in return but I keep on failing with it.

```
$this->load->model("base/discussions_service");
$test = ["Discussion1","Discussion2"];

$res = $this->discussions_service->get_all(array("uri" => $test), array("content"));
```

So basically as you can see I am passing array of URI's but I keep on getting empty results for some reason

Comment: You mean `"uri" => [ '$in' => $test ]`. You also really should find "one" array notation and stick to it. Changing from `[]` to `array()` is just making your code confusing for others to read. Hint: `[]` was introduced to make code clearer.

Comment: Thanks ! That works and Ill take your suggestion!